# Host an MVC 3 with Razor syntax app on old server

Tags: c#, mvc, server, project-hosting, razor

I just started a new job, I have to create a web app for them and host it on their intranet on an Windows 2003 R2 server with SQL server 2008.

As said in the question, I'll work on a MCV3 with Razor syntax application.

I know that it won't work easily or even not work at all.

On a recent server you have to install something more (I don't remember the name) for the Razor to be understood. What about on this old server? Will I get it to work or should I tell them to buy a more up to date server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally commented on the previous answer but I wanted my list with a correct layout so :

Just use MS's Web Platform Installer to install the framework and MVC3, and yes, it'll be as simple as that.

I did that and had two little other things to do, maybe linked to my 64 bit server :

1. Run "aspet_regiis.exe -ir" to install ASP.Net
2. Install VC++ 2008 SP1 (don't know how but it fixed some DLLs I couldn't get to work) microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092

Answer (score 2):

MVC3 will work on IIS 6. You just have to install .NET 4 and ASP.NET MVC 3 from the following link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3
The Razor view engine already comes with ASP.NET MVC 3, so you don't have to install anything else.

Comment: I don't think it is as simple as that. But I'll let you know as things progress.

Comment: It is that simple, just make sure to run `aspnet_regiis -ir` in the `%Windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.xxx\` directory to apply the framework to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Install is pretty easy -- šljaker has that nailed.

The other trick is url handling. IIS7 makes it very easy to do a totally managed pipeline. For IIS6 you either need to resort to tricks like adding extensions onto your controllers -- such as the suggested pattern of http://www.example.com/somecontroller.mvc/someaction or a perhaps more palatable http://www.example.com/somecontroller/someaction.aspx to get IIS6 to use the aspnet_isapi module to handle the request. Another option would be to use a wildcard mapping but that creates a bit of extra strain for static content such as images and stylesheets which might or might not matter to you.

Personally, I would encourage them to upgrade the server OS if at all possible though, really not worth fighting with a 10 year old server stack for most things.